# Test Class for Opportunity Update

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I have a test class where I am trying to cover code on an update trigger when the Effective Date or Stage is changed.  However, when I run the test, none of the Opportunity data gets changed.  Do I have the proper syntax in my test to test for a change to the Opportunity?

```
static testmethod void testAcctData(){

    Account acct5 = TestCreateRecords.createAcct(0);
    insert acct5;

    Opportunity opp1 = TestCreateRecords.createOppNew(acct5.Id);
    insert opp1;

Test.startTest();
    Opportunity opp1a = [SELECT Id,Effective_Date__c,StageName
                        FROM Opportunity
                        WHERE Id =: opp1.Id];
        opp1a.Effective_Date__c = Date.TODAY().addDays(5);
        opp1a.StageName = 'Phase 5: Closed Won';
        UPDATE opp1a;

Test.stopTest();
}
```

***Trigger:***

```
//Used when renewal Opportunity Effective Date is updated
    public void mgdUpdate(List<Opportunity> MgdAcctUpdates, map<Id,Opportunity> oldMap){

    Map<Id,Account> acctMap = new Map<Id,Account>();
    Set<id> Ids = new Set<id>();

    String recordTypeName = 'Renewals';
    Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtMapByName = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
    Schema.RecordTypeInfo rtInfo =  rtMapByName.get(recordTypeName);
    id recType = rtInfo.getRecordTypeId();

//    List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        for (Opportunity opp : MgdAcctUpdates){
                Ids.add(opp.AccountId);
            }

     Map<Id,Account> acctMap2 = new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Id,Name,Managed_Renewal_Date__c,Managed_Term__c,Managed_Value__c
                                                    FROM Account
                                                    WHERE Id in :Ids]);

        for (Opportunity opp2 : MgdAcctUpdates){

system.debug('***%##%*** Record Type: '+opp2.RecordTypeId+' AcctId: '+opp2.AccountId+' Eff Date: '+opp2.Effective_Date__c+' Old Date: '+oldMap.get(opp2.Id).Effective_Date__c+' Stage Name: '+opp2.StageName+' Old Stage: '+oldMap.get(opp2.Id).StageName);
            if(opp2.RecordTypeId == recType && acctMap2.containsKey(opp2.AccountId) && (opp2.Effective_Date__c <> oldMap.get(opp2.Id).Effective_Date__c || opp2.StageName <> oldMap.get(opp2.Id).StageName)) {

                Account acct = acctMap2.get(opp2.AccountId);
                        acct.Managed_Renewal_Date__c = opp2.Renewal_Date_Next__c;
                        acct.Managed_Term__c = opp2.Term__c;
                        acct.Managed_Value__c = opp2.Final_Annualized_Amount__c;

                        if(opp2.IsWon || !opp2.IsClosed){
                            acct.Managed_Status__c = 'Active';
                        }
                        else{
                            acct.Managed_Status__c = 'Lost';
                        }
                 acctMap.put(acct.id,acct);
            }

            }
        update acctMap.values();
        }
```

Comment: Can you share some of the trigger logic

Comment: I added to my post.

Comment: In the method createOppNew, are you setting the correct information on the opportunity? Some potential issues I see are the recordType on the opp1 not matching what you have in the if, also some problems might be at the Effective Data field and the Stage name. When you run the test class in the developer console, does the code coverage pass the if statement right after the system.debug?

Comment: No, that's the issue is that the Effective Date and Stage Name are not being changed, although I thought the code in my test was doing that.  The Record Type is correct.

Comment: But do you initially set the Effective Date and the Stage Name in the method createOppNew? And if yes, does it fulfills the if statement based on the logic operators?

Comment: Yes, they are set in the CreateOppNew method.  The Insert part of the trigger is covered 100%.  This test is set to measure the Update part of the trigger, but the values are not changing so the If statement is not being satisfied.

Comment: You have to change the values in the unit test. Once the opportunity is inserted, you have to make sure that Effective_Date__c = Date.TODAY().addDays(5) is different then when you created the opportunity and the opp1a.StageName = 'Phase 5: Closed Won' is different from when you created the opportunity.

Comment: Yes, they are both different from the value when the Opportunity is inserted.